# How to access the sub object of your array object using useReducer

Tags: reactjs

I got external js data that have a sub-object nested. I'm importing this data into my index. The question is how can I access the listoftask, so that if I want to add a task to this user. Tried to console.log the data and the output is the entire array but if i tried to data.listoftask the output is undefined. How to the make the listoftask to be my defaultState.

Thanks!

```
Data.js
export const data = [
  {
    user: 'John Doe',
    listoftask: [
      {
        id: 1, name: 'John Doe'
      }
    ]
  },
];


index.js
const defaultState = {
  task: data
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the listoftask you can use the `map`

```
var listoftask=data.map(item=>item.listoftask)

console.lo(listoftask)===>///[{id: 1 ,name: "John Doe"}]

 console.lo(data)===>///[{user: 'John Doe', listoftask: [{ id: 1, name: 'John Doe' }]},]
```